# Generate link_to using :url =>

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm generating a link with a confirmation message and am having trouble with how the confirmation message is getting included.

I have tried this with both `rails 4.0.10` and `rails 4.2.2` and it produces the same output.

Here is my `link_to` code:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', :url => [comment.article, comment], :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => "are you sure?" -%>
```

And it generates the following link:

```
<a data-remote="true" href="/articles/4?confirm=are+you+sure%3F&amp;method=delete&amp;url%5B%5D=4&amp;url%5B%5D=5">Destroy Comment</a>
```

This is obviously doesn't work because it's putting the javascript confirm message right into the url of the link.

I've found that if I remove the `:url =>` from the `link_to` it seems to work fine.

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.article, comment], :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => "are you sure?" -%>

<a confirm="are you sure?" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/articles/4/comments/5">Destroy Comment</a>
```

Is there a way to fix this and **keep** the `:url =>` in the `link_to`? I really like having the `:url =>` in there for specificity purposes. I looked through the api docs but couldn't find a specific answer. There was one comment made that claims something like this should work. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to#1227-link-to-with-as-routing

Comment: Where did you find about that `:url` option, the documentation for both `link_to` and `url_for` don't mention it, other than the comment you pointed (on a third party website) there is no other mention about it. Also remember Rails favors convention over configuration, any Rails developer will know how the URL is being built, without explicitly calling it `:url`.

Comment: @Leito - It's from an older rails app that I'm working on ( I'm not the original creator of the app ).

Comment: Please edit your question to include what version of Rails you are using, that's critical information for solving this.

Comment: Updated with rails versions. I've tried both `4.0.10` and `4.2.2`

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you are passing a hash as second parameter, which matches this method signature:

```
link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
```

causing Rails to interpret it as `url_options`, which is why you get that link you get.

If you really want to user the `:url=>`, then you can create your own helper method, say `link_to_with_url` that that expects hash containing `:url` key as the second parameter:

```
def link_to_with_url(body, options={})   
  url = options.delete(:url); 
  if url.nil?
     raise "Can't link to something that doesn't have a URL"
  else
     link_to body, url, options
  end
end
```

You can also overload Rails' `link_to` method, but I would advise against that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', :url => [comment.article, comment], :method => :delete, :remote => true, :data => {:confirm => "are you sure?"} %>
```